# What is number of faces in a k-ary n-dim cube?

Tags: geometry, polytopes

What is the number of $(n-r)$ dim faces for a $k$-ary $n$-dim cube ?

Definition of k-ary cube: In  a $k$- ary $n$- cube ,  each  node  is  identified  by  an $n$-bit  base-$k$ address $b_{n − 1},...b_j,...b_0$ , and for each dimension $j =0,1,...n − 1$, the node is connected by edges to nodes with addresses $b_{n − 1},...,b_j ± 1 (mod k ),...b_0 $. For details check [this paper's introduction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.127.1159&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

To put this thing simply: when we consider a unit square, or a unit cube or a unit n-dim cube each of it's vertices can be represented as: $\{0,1\}^n$. So
this is an example of $k=2$. To generalize this idea we can assume $k$ as any +ve integer and is called as $k$-ary $n$-dim cube.

e.g: for $k=2, n = 3$ it's unit 3-d cube:

$(r=1)$the number of $3-1 = 2$ (dim)-faces = 6

$(r=2)$the number of $ 3-2 = 1$ (dim) faces i.e edges = 12

Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: You put "polytope" and "geometry" as your tags, but when you say "base-$k$ address" and then define what looks like $k$ axis parallel edges that all lie on a common line, things get confusing. Do you actually have a polytope geometry description (i.e., list of inequalities, list of points that form a convex hull, etc.) so that people know what your polytope is intended to look like? Probably it's in the paper but the way your question's phrased, there's no way to answer without reading that paper unless someone already knows what a "$k$-ary $n$ cube" is. So no need for your current definition.